# How to highlight in the mode-line that a compilation process is running in AUCTeX?

Tags: auctex, mode-line, compilation

As compiling LaTeX documents can take a while, I would like to be able to quickly and effortlessly check whether the compilation process is still runing. How can I achieve this with AUCTeX? I know I could take a look at the log with <kbd>C-c C-l</kbd> and scroll to the bottom, but that doesn't really feel effortless. On the other hand, constantly following the log buffer (as with `TeX-show-compilation`) is not nice either. Instead, I imagine, e.g., some (maybe animated) tag/icon appearing in the mode-line similarly to "Loading" when updating the package information:

[image]

**Update**

As giordano has pointed out, actually the tag "Compilation" appears somewhere in the mode-line, yet this is easy to overlook. I guess my question then is whether it is possible to make this tag more visible, similarly to the TeX output buffer:

[image]

Comment: In the mode-line there is `Compilation` string if a compilation is running.

Comment: @giordano OMG, I've overlooked it. Is there a way to make it more prominent, as when using `TeX-show-compilation`?

Comment: Not really, currently this mode-line is hard-coded, with no possibility for users to customize it.  However, I don't understand how would you like to highlight it.

Comment: @giordano I would like to have it appear immediately right of the major mode tag, not just somewhere in the list of active minor modes. The examples in the question should make this clear: when loading or updating packages, this is indicated next to "Paradox Menu"; when looking at the LaTeX log, the status of compilation is shown next to "TeX Output". See what I mean?